# How to trigger functions in a component of Angular with TinyMce?

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular8

Currently I am trying to let the editor of TinyMce trigger a local function when a button of it triggers 'onAction', but it does not accept any variable with 'this.'.

```
        onAction: function () {
          alert('Button clicked!');
          if (this.fileUpload) {
            this.fileUpload.nativeElement.click();
          }
          // Cannot use any function or variable with 'this.'
        }
```

While this is not triggering, this is triggering:

```
        onAction: this.postMessage()
```

But for some reason, this will trigger every time the component is initialized (and not clicked). The onAction is bonded with a button which supposed to be triggered only on click, but it doesn't work in that way.

Comment: Create a sample stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bx1bv5 to replicate your issue and let us know link so that we can look  into your problem.

Comment: @Afsar Hi Afsar, I just put my code there but I don't know how to install tinymce in that editor. Can you do that for me please?

Comment: save your code there and share link, you will get different link on save.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tdsdzv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts @Afsar

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `function` to declare your functions. The scope is now within that function. If you use arrow functions instead it will work.

So it would be:

```
onAction: () => {
      alert('Button clicked!');
      if (this.fileUpload) {
        this.fileUpload.nativeElement.click();
      }
    }
```

Note that you'll have to change the function where you create the button as well. Right now you probably have something like this from the TinyMCE documentation:

```
setup: function (editor) {
```

You want to change that to an arrow function also:

```
setup: (editor) => {
```